# Perl replace string (newstring oldstring)

Tags: perl

Implement a program that processes an input file by changing every occurrence of an old string into a new string.  (The usage is: chstr file oldstring newstring, chstr is your program name, file, oldstring and newstring are parameters specified by user.)

```
if( @ARGV < 2)
{    
print "usage: ReplaceString.pl filename OldString NewString\n";
print "   example: perl ReplaceString.pl intelliquest.txt ";
print "IntelliQuest Kantar > kantar.txt\n";
exit 0;
}
$OldString = $ARGV[1];
$NewString = $ARGV[2];
open(MYFILE,$ARGV[0]) || die "Cannot open file \"$ARGV[0]\"";
while($line = &lt;MYFILE&gt;)
{
$line =~ s/$OldString/$NewString/g;
print STDOUT $line;
}
```

really not sure what is wrong here, I try and run

```
jd@jd-laptop:~/Desktop$ perl HW1-2.pl text.txt if the
```

To replace if with the and i get...

```
syntax error at HW1-2.pl line 11, near "&lt;"
syntax error at HW1-2.pl line 11, near "&gt"
syntax error at HW1-2.pl line 15, near "}"
Execution of HW1-2.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Do i need the &lt and &gt?  I'm really new to Perl

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why do you avoid indenting your programs properly? This is barely readable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Whatever tutorial you based this on was clearly written by someone who can't be bothered to check his work.  `&lt;` and `&gt;` are supposed to be `<` and `>`, respectively, but somewhere along the line it got overly HTML-encoded.

Specifically, the line

```
while($line = &lt;MYFILE&gt;)
```

should be changed to:

```
while($line = <MYFILE>)
```

Comment: jd@jd-laptop:~/Desktop$ perl HW1-2.pl text.txt the if
syntax error at HW1-2.pl line 13, near "=>;"
syntax error at HW1-2.pl line 13, near "<;"
syntax error at HW1-2.pl line 17, near "}"           I still get this

Answer (score 0):

[jwodder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19304208/368630) has the answer, but you seem confused by it:

This works on my Mac. If you are running this on a Linux, Mac, or Unix system, you need that
first line I have `#! /usr/bin/env perl`. Or else, you need to run your program as `perl ReplaceString.pl` from the command line.

One Windows, you have to make sure that the `.pl` suffix is mapped to your Perl interpreter.

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

if( @ARGV < 2) {    
    print "usage: ReplaceString.pl filename OldString NewString\n";
    print "   example: perl ReplaceString.pl intelliquest.txt ";
    print "IntelliQuest Kantar > kantar.txt\n";
    exit 0;
}
$OldString = $ARGV[1];
$NewString = $ARGV[2];

open(MYFILE,$ARGV[0]) || die "Cannot open file \"$ARGV[0]\"";

while( $line = <MYFILE> ) {
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/$OldString/$NewString/g;
    print "$line\n";
}
```

I take it your taking lessons and learning Perl.

I'm just curious where you're learning Perl. This is syntax I would expect to see back in the old Perl 3.x days. Perl has advanced quite a bit since then, and I would think your teacher would help you with the newer style of syntax.